# Failed merge in EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, egit

I did a fetch from my remote origin to get the latest master branch that my friend had pushed to. I wanted to merge with my own master after the fetch, but whenever I do a merge with origin/master it just says "Failed". I've made hard resets before trying again with same result.

Since "Failed" is pretty vague I'm asking here what to do.

[image: Merge failed]

I have looked on the [Egit wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Possible_merge_results), but they don't mention failure as a possible result. [This tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/egit-tutorial/) says that "A Failed result may occur when there are already conflicting changes in the working directory.", that's all I've found by googling.

Egit 2.2.0
Eclipse Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: It almost sounds like someone did a rebase while they had "master" checked out, or they amended a commit they had already pushed. The history of that shared branch would have gotten rewritten and out of synch with your local copy of that branch. That causes all manors of pain and suffering in Git.

Comment: Thanks for your input. All suggestions on how to narrow it down are welcome, I wrote it in a hurry but will add more info.

Comment: If you have files showing up as "modified" or "deleted" in your working directory, the merge will fail. You will either need to stash those changes, or commit them before merging.

Comment: Yeah the confusing part is that I did hard resets before trying. That's supposed to reset my working directory, right?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was Egit failed a merge without saying why.

After playing around in the staging view and, by a leap of faith from someone not entirely comfortable with Git, added all the unstaged files to the index (which is strange since I did a hard reset, why should there be differences?) I committed it. After I had done the commit, another file (a .jar) popped up in the unstaged list (why wasn't it there until I made my commit? Seriously). I added it to the index and committed. Finally there were no unstaged files.

I tried merging, and it worked. At last I got the "conflicted" result instead of "failed". Added everything to index and committed. Finally I seemed to have merged successfully, and I could push.

Honestly can't tell if I made mistakes or if Egit doesn't work properly.

Comment: This may have been caused by [JGit bug 372834](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372834) which is about not handling files correctly that have CRLF newlines in the repository when the `core.autocrlf` option is set. With your first commit, you committed the files and they now have LF in the repository, which fixes the problem.

Comment: That's interesting, especially the reported date of the bug (since I'm not familiar with the inner workings of EGit or JGit). I am working on a pc with a mac user, that might be it. So why does EGit use JGit instead of some other implementation?

Answer (score 0):

In the Git repositories view.
1. right click the local -> master branch
2. select push branch -> next 
3. it pop up a 'select push destination' window, check the 'force update' in it.